# Arguments version of setValuesForKeysWithDictionary

Tags: objective-c, kvc

Is there an easy way in Objective-C to set all the arguments from a method as properties on the class? Similar to setValuesForKeysWithDictionary, but more along the lines of "setValuesForKeysWithArguments"?

Fake example:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *foo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *bar;

- (id)initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo Bar:(NSString *)bar;

@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo Bar:(NSString *)bar{
    // Mythical implementation begins here
    [self setValuesForKeysWithArguments:theArgumentsWeJustPassedToThisMethod];
}
@end
```

Comment: A temporary dictionary... Technically you could do some reflection on the method but that would be more code for little maintenance benefit.

Comment: What advantage will you get? This is done just once, and then never required to do something in your model. You create objects throughout the application and simply call `[someClassObject initWithFoo:@"a" Bar:"b"];`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This is a simple example. What I'm working with actually takes 5 arguments. I realize that this isn't a huge time save, but when you're working with Objective-C all day long those little shortcuts that save time and cut down boilerplate really add up.